# JTextPane not triggering UndoableEditListener events

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I added an UndoManager to a JTextPane in my application, but I can't get it work:

```
UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();
textpane.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);
```

When I manually type into the text pane, then try to undo the changes, nothing ever happens `undoManager.canUndo()` always returns false.

I also tried another way of adding the manager as follows:

```
textpane.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener()
{
    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened( UndoableEditEvent e )
    {
        System.out.println("UndoableEditEvent");
        undoMgr.addEdit(e.getEdit());
    }
});
```

With the above code I can see in the output window that the `undoableEditHappened( UndoableEditEvent e )` is called once at the start (most likely by a `read` call which loads the test file). When I make changes (via keyword) or `insertText(...)` calls, there are no further listener calls.

I found some similar questions here in StackOverflow, but the solutions were always alongs the lines that they had custom input methods for the `JTextPane`, I don't ... not that I know of.

What might I have overlooked?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example. The tutorial also has a section on `Implement Undo and Redo`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the `UndoableEditListener` wasn't triggering.

I was calling `JTextPane.read(Reader reader, Object object)` after I had setup the `Document` listeners - What I didn't know was that calling the `read(...)` method creates and adds a new `Document` model to the `JTextPane`, which basically removed anything I had previously done to the *old* `Document`.

**Solution**

Work with the `Document` model **after** calling `JTextPane.read(...)`